# Java: check if datepicker has value error

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, null

I have a

```
DatePicker date = new DatePicker();
date.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```

The field is still manually editable, so you can just remove the initial set value.

I have a button with which I want to check if the `DatePicker` value is empty. But when I do `if(date.getValue().equals(null)`, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
         if(date.getValue().equals(null) {
            // do something
         }
     }
   });
```

How can I properly check if the value is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call methods on a `null` reference. As you've seen, that would produce a `NullPointerException`. Instead, you should use the `==` operator to check that the reference is [not] `null`:

```
if (date.getValue() == null) {
    // Here --------^
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (date.getValue().equals(null) { ... }
```

If the value is really a `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` exception. So, you'd better write like:

```
if (date.getValue() == null) { ... }
```

Keep in mind, if you use `equals`, you should be sure that the left part of an expression (an instance this method is called on) never presents a `null` (like constants, `String` literals, enums do).

---

Also, you are free to replace an anonymous class with a lambda for conciseness:

```
btn.setOnAction(event -> { ... });
```

Furthermore, there's a good one-line way to set a default value if the current is a `null` (to `LocalDate.now()`, for example):

```
datePicker.setValue(Optional.ofNullable(datePicker.getValue()).orElse(LocalDate.now()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for null with

```
if (datePicker.getValue() == null) {
    //...
}
```